# MSBuild IIS issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, msbuild

I'm using MSBuild to package and publish an my Asp.Net MVC 3, .Net 4 Application. I've already successfully done this for an MVC 1.0, .Net 3.5 application.

Whenever I include the IIS Settings (`IncludeIisSettings=true`) in my .proj file I get the following build error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2046,
>   5): error MSB4044: The "EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not
>   given a value for the required parameter "Text".

Comment: This seem to occur when `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` is empty, which in turn pass an empty value to the "Text" parameter as referenced in the error. A rebuild may help.

Comment: A had the same error, after migrate a azure cloud service webrole to a webapp. Setting IncludeIisSettings to False in the .csproj solves it.

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same issue on my build server.

The package would build perfectly on my development machine but would fail with the exact same error you have on my build server. For me the problem was caused by the fact that on my build machine, the application is not registered with IIS.

The problem started when I enabled local testing in IIS Express in the project and in some indirect way that enables the `IncludeIisSettings=true` setting you mentioned. This causes the web deployment pipeline to query IIS for the site's details. Since the build server did not have IIS 7 or IIS Express installed it could not get those settings. This ultimately leads to the error above because the parameter passed to the `EscapeTextForRegularExpressions` task is empty.

My solution was to set `IncludeIisSettings` to `False` in the applications *.wpp.targets* file (see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment) for an example .wpp.targets file). If you specify the settings for IIS explicitly, that should not be a problem.

I was also able to fix the build by registering the site with IIS Express using WebMatrix. Running the site in Visual Studio should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was with permissions, specifically UAC settings in Windows 7 after switching laptops.

After close inspection against my previous configuration I realized I still had the default UAC Settings. To change go to `Start > Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Change User Account Control Settings`. Then drag the bar all the way down to `Never notify`.

Here are some additional symptoms I observed which could be helpful:

When I ran msbuild locally with `IncludeIisSettings=true` I received the same error as in the question.

After some frustration and wrong turns I couldn't figure out why although I am an administrator I was getting permission errors in relevant areas, e.g. when setting `IncludeIisSettings=false` then attempting to run the deploy file I received a permission error.

Thus I decided to explore the UAC settings and find the solution.

Comment: Didn't help me unfortunately. I run VS as admin, turned UAC to lowest and still have the same error. But good for you! (Windows 10, tried with includ iis setting on and off)

Answer (score 0):

The solution we found to have the IncludeIisSettings=true and have a succefull build with out the "The "EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Text"." error was:

- Install Visual Studio on the Build Server (already done).
- Install IIS on the Build Server.
- In IIS, on the Default Website, add a binding for https (port 443) and use the certificate installed by Visual Studio (IIS Express Development Certificate).

Answer (score -1):

I had to change the following in the properties\Web of the web application

in the Servers Section  change it from IISExpress to Local IIS  and  create  my vitural directory.  Of Course you naturally have to to have IIS installed on your machine.