# EscapeTextForRegularExpressions error while webdeploying to azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

In my asp.ent MVC4 project, I am using webdeploy to deploy to azure and I deployed this project to the app service on azure several times before. but out of a sudden I have this error.

```
"EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Text"
```

> **I Have found an answer:**

Add this file into the web project in its root folder.

```
File Name : *.wpp.targets


<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Internal">
          <FromTarget>*.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
        </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

> Never the less I cannot understand the real cause of the problem

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957222/msbuild-iis-issue) noted the `IncludeIisSettings` within *.csproj. Per my test, if I specified the `<IncludeIisSettings>true</IncludeIisSettings>` with my csproj, then when I use the Web Deploy method from the Publish wizard of VS, I could encounter the similar issue as follows:

[image]

After remove the `IncludeIisSettings` or set the value to false, then I could deploy my web application to azure web app successfully.

Comment: I am deploying to azure, so the IIS copying was not an issue and I have not selected it in the first place.

Comment: Never the less, Thank you very much I have fixed it and I have added the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I have another answer maybe can help someone:

You must open the Solution explorer then right-click the project, select properties, on Package/Publish Web check your Configuration is on Release and not on Active (Debug) in the drop-down, this was the solution in my case.