# Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3088,5): Error MSB4044 when building using Azure Pipelines

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm moving my build process from my local machine to a self-hosted agent using Azure Pipelines. I'm encountering this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3088,5): Error MSB4044: The "EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Text"

The solution's main project is a WebApi2 project and it has a number of publish profiles. The setting `Include IIS settings as configured in IIS Express` is not selected.

The MSBuild parameters are:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Should this CI part just build the project, and the CD part publish the artifact using web deploy to a site that I configure in `Releases`?

Do I need to change the above parameters?

I've created `wpp.targets` files with the following content:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeIisSettings>false</IncludeIisSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>   
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Internal">
      <FromTarget>MyApp.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957222/msbuild-iis-issue . If you still have this issue, can you provide more information about "The setting Include IIS settings as configured in IIS Express is not selected"?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Didn't proceed with Azure Pipelines. Have to postpone for now.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Updated my question... still doesn't work.